# Bootstrap Angular 2 app with a provider that requires asynchronous initialization

Tags: angular, bootstrapping

I'd like to keep my Angular 2 app config in a separate config.json file that is loaded when the app is bootstrapped.

I plan to serve the config data via ConfigService. But it needs to fetch the data from the file before any other component can ask for it.

My app is currently bootstrapped like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent, routes } from './app';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routes
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  [
    ConfigService,
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
```

So I am looking for a way how to init the ConfigService before the app is bootstrapped. Or maybe init it when the app is bootstrapped but make any consumer wait until it is done loading.

Comment: If you will put your logic inside constructor of service it'll be executed before app bootstraped or components initiated

Answer (score 0):

Following high level may works:

1. Wrap your current app inside a `ShellComponent` which has following template

   ```
   <div *ngIf="ready">
       <app-component></app-component>
   </div>
   ```
2. `ShellComponent` will call `ConfigService` in `ngOnInit()`. In callback set `ready` to `true` when `ConfigService` return the config.

Instead of bootstrapping `AppComponent`, you bootstrap `ShellComponent`.