# how to pass an argument/parameter to an angular application at deploy time

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an angular application and it has some configuration parameters that it reads from a config file, the application loads and the configuration parameters are read and the app is ready to do its work.

Lets simplify and think there is only one parameter.
I want to change that and instead of hard coding the parameter, i want to pass that parameter to the angular app at run time, when the application first gets loaded.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to set the parameter at build/deploy time, or at run time? Two very different things.

Comment: Your question is almost identical (parameter vs config file) to another question, check my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42987447/1810391).

Comment: @Timo run time really

Comment: @JohnSiu Not seeing how your response replaces reading a config file with a runtime parameter to the angular app

Comment: @reza Aren't you going to put that parameter in a config file? Or do you actually mean those `--production`, `--development` parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters rendered from backend to angular2 bootstrap method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611549/how-to-pass-parameters-rendered-from-backend-to-angular2-bootstrap-method)

Comment: @JohnSiu, no config file, no build/deploy time parameters settings. Only at runtime

Comment: Something like this? `npm start --prod` ?